# Inline element's width set before JSON content loads

Tags: html, css, ajax

I have a problem with an inline element, specifically an `<a>` element. It is as follows:

```
<a class="text></a>

.text{
display:inline-block;
background:red;
padding:5px
}
```

The problem is that I load in the text it holds with JSON. Now I want the background of it to be the length of the text, but the problem is the html loads then the json loads so it doesn't pick up the length of the text. I could set a fixed width but I'd rather it be the size of the text. Do I have any options? Thanks!

EDIT: Seems to cause problems is chrome more than any other browser.

JAvascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var data;
function loadContent(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/content.json",
        data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(source){
            data = source;
            showInfo();
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Failed to load content");
        }
    }); 

}

loadContent();
    function showInfo(){
        $(".text").html(data[lang]['startpage']['text']);
}
});
```

Comment: I think we need a more complete example, setting the text on `.text` will change its width and height to the size of the text + 5px on each side for the `padding`.

Comment: problem is it sets its width before the text is loaded in. So it has only the padding and no real width.

Comment: Setting the text using JavaScript should recalculate the size of `.text` though

Comment: sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't, it's not reliable, depends on speed of load i suppose

Comment: This is very dependant on the browser as well, you may want to add your browser to the question.

Comment: seems to cause problems in chrome

Comment: Post your JavaScript as well, it works perfectly fine from my experience in Chrome.

Comment: added the Javascript too now

Comment: you can see the problem here: http://alexanderlloyd.info/test/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% if this will fix your problem but try doing it like this, passing `source` into the function instead of using your (undeclared) `data` variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function loadContent(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/content.json",
        data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: showInfo,
        error: function(data){
            alert("Failed to load content");
        }
    }); 

}

loadContent();

function showInfo(data){
    $(".text").html(data[lang]['startpage']['text']);
}
});
```

### Update

To get all your divs on the same line change `#game-nav` from `inline` to `inline-block`.

```
#game-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

`display:inline` elements (like `<b>` or `<span>` wrap which is not what you want here, inline-block can wrap to the new line but they won't break mid-word.

Comment: I actually do declare the data variable, I added that too to the code

Comment: Are you certain `data[lang]['startpage']['text']` is correct? Try this before setting the html and see if it's correct `alert(data[lang]['startpage']['text']);`

Comment: it iis correct, it loads correctly but the width is set before load